# ASMX Web service migration to wcf

Tags: wcf, asmx

We have developed the wcf service with the existing web service code. the existing customer wants to consume that service only changing the new url. They do not want to replace the proxy class. is it possible in any case.

The customer is able to consume the same with replacing the proxy and config. but he does not want to replace the proxy. please share ur comments whether it is possible or not.

Comment: What was "the web service" and what is "the wcf service"? If you mean you replaced an ASMX SOAP 1.1 service with a WCF service, you can add a basicHttpBinding to your WCF service to let it act as a SOAP 1.1 service, see [WCF, ASMX Basic HTTP binding and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058755/wcf-asmx-basic-http-binding-and-iis).

Comment: @CodeCaster: is basicHttpBinding enough in this case? It would be if they could replace the proxy class, but won't they also need to force the use of the XML Serializer?

Comment: @John I'm not entirely sure, I haven't been able to "hot-swap" an ASMX service with a WCF service without having to regenerate the client.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this by configuring an endpoint using `basicHttpBinding`. I believe you will also need to force the use of the XML Serializer, and I don't know how to do that offhand, so someone else will have to help you with that. I'm concerned that there could still be small differences that would cause errors using the same proxy class.

On the other hand, if performance isn't the top consideration, you could create an ASMX service using the original class and method attributes from the old service. This ASMX service would then call the WCF service.

BTW, the ASMX service could call the WCF service on a fast endpoint. If they were running on the same server, they could use `netNamedPipesBinding`, for instance, but in any case could use `netTcpBinding`, which uses binary over TCP/IP. That would mitigate the performance difference from the extra hop.